# Java sax parsing replacing a custom tag with the resolved value

Tags: java, parsing, tags, sax

I have an XML String which is actually an HTML. It contains few custom tags that should be read and replaced with actual value. I am unable to figure out how to do this using SAX parsing

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>The joiner report for today</p>
    <p><APP:FT value="THIS_WEEKDAY"/></p>
    <p>&#160;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This template would be evaluated using a SAX parsing and java code, where the value of the custom tag

```
<APP:FT>
```

would be evaluated using java code. For example

```
<APP:FT value="THIS_WEEKDAY"/>
```

should be replaced by TUESDAY considering today is 13-Dec-2016. It is easy to find the value, but I am unable to figure out a way to replace this in the HTML string. The final HTML should look like

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>The joiner report for today</p>
    <p>TUESDAY</p>
    <p>&#160;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably want [XSL transformation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt), not SAX.  The [javax.xml.transform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/package-summary.html) package supports XSLT.

Comment: Thank you folks for reading through. i solved the problem not by XML but by using freemarker template API [http://freemarker.org/](http://freemarker.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you folks for reading through. i solved the problem not by XML but by using freemarker template API - http://freemarker.org/